# Mean of "ブランドによって消費量が違う"

Tags: manga

Very stupid question - what mean of text in a last frame of this yonkoma (https://ibb.co/eWGxYv)?
From "ブランドによって消費量が違う" I'm think about some brand tea with big amount of tea leaves. But I'm see empty cup.
And i can't read part of left text. "ダブルワリー??好きなのか" - what symbols in a place of question marks?

Answer (score 2):

> 「ブランドによって消費量{しょうひりょう}が違{ちが}う」

means:

> "Different amounts (of drink) are consumed (by her) depending on the brands."

More informally,

> "How much she drinks depends on the brand (of the drink)."

Look inside the three cups carefully and you will find three different amounts of drink left in them.

Finally, the hand-written line reads:

> 「ダブルクリームが好きなのか・・・」

which means:

> "She must like the Double Cream the best..."